# Istio + NetworkPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubernetes-networkpolicy

How to explicitly allow inter-pod communication on a bare-metal cluster running Istio 1.8.4?
What I try is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all
  namespace: default
spec:
  policyTypes: [Ingress, Egress]
  podSelector: {}
  ingress: [] 
  egress: []
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  policyTypes: [Ingress, Egress]
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp

  ingress:
    - ports:
        - port: 8000
        - port: 6666 
      from:
        - podSelector:
            matchLabels:
              istio: ingress

  egress:
    - to:
      ports:
        - port: 8000
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 53
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 15012
          protocol: TCP
        - port: 15020
          protocol: TCP
```

Sidecar is unable to connect to the control plane.

---

Another question: how to restrict inter-pod communication if in most cases pods communicate via `istio-ingressgateway`?

Comment: What you mean by `Sidecar is unable to connect to the control plane`? Could you please add the error you see? As for the second question, why most of these pods communicate via istio-ingressgateway? According to [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2017/0.1-using-network-policy/#enforce-fine-grained-isolation-within-the-application) I would say that's not a best practice to do, as they should communicate directly, but maybe that's the only way you can configure it. Have you tried with [authorization policy](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/security/authorization-policy/)?

Comment: DNS protocol is UDP, so protocol of port 53 should be ``UPD`` not ``TCP``. What does the sidecar log say? It should error log the reason, something like can't connect to istiod.

Comment: Pods don't communicate via the istio-ingressgateway. Only the external traffic comes through there (from eg. a load balancer). Your pods can communicate freely between themselves within the cluster (given the NetworkPolicy/AuthorizationPolicy allows). Also, only TCP/15012 and UDP/53 are needed to access kube-dns or istiod.